# Cache in Firebase Hosting Custom Domain

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I am using Firebase hosting.

I noticed that sometimes deployments are not pushed to my custom domain associated with my account.

So changes happen in:

myurl.firebaseapp.com

But not on

Myurl.io

Is this Firebase related?

Comment: This sounds more like something for Firebase support. Can you mail details to firebase-support@google.com?

Comment: The issue should now be resolved. It it isn't, please reach out to Firebase support.

Comment: Thank you! Yes it works now!

Answer (score 1):

Using firebase.json you can define and control cache. The following json snippet let you define the cache for 1 year for  the images.

`{
        "source" :"**/*.@(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)",
        "headers" : [ {
          "key" : "Cache-Control",
          "value" : "max-age=30672000"
        } ]
}`

Source: [How To Enable Caching With Google Firebase Hosting?](https://www.isrgrajan.com/articles/computer/how-to-enable-caching-with-google-firebase-hosting/)